# C permutation with memcpy issues

Tags: c, unix, memcpy

Given an array of any type (integers in this case) and a Map that tells what indexes are supposed to be swapped in an array. I am attempting to make a clean swap, but running into issues with the way I am using memcpy.

Here is what I have so far:

Goal: given a data array of [1,3,-1,2] and a mapping of [[0,3],[3,2],[2,1],[1,0]], a clean permutation would be [3,-1,2,1].

My current implementation : 0 3 -1 2... I think I have an off-by-one error somewhere.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#define MAP_SIZE 4

typedef struct MapEntry {
    int indexFrom;
    int indexTo;
} MapEntry;

typedef MapEntry * Map;

int permute(void *data, int nblobs, int szblob, const Map map);

void build_map(Map);
void build_data(int *);
int is_map_valid(Map);
void print_map(Map);
int is_valid(Map);

int map_comparator(const void * a, const void * b);

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    int nblobs, * data, i;
    size_t szblob;
    Map map = (Map)malloc(sizeof(Map));
    data = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int) * 4);

    build_map(map);

    data[0] = 1;
    data[1] = 3;
    data[2] = -1;
    data[3] = 2;

    nblobs = 4;
    szblob = sizeof(int);

    if (!permute(data, nblobs, szblob, map)) {
        printf("Invalid Map\n");
        return 0;
    }

    i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < szblob; ++i) {
        printf("%d ", data[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}

void print_map(Map map){
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < MAP_SIZE; ++i) {
        printf("[%d - %d]\n", map[i].indexFrom, map[i].indexTo);
    }
}

int map_comparator(const void *a, const void *b)
{
    const MapEntry *s1 = a;
    const MapEntry *s2 = b;
    if (s2->indexFrom != s1->indexFrom) {
        return s1->indexFrom - s2->indexFrom;
    } else {
        return s1->indexTo - s2->indexTo;
    }
}

int is_map_valid(Map map) {
    int i,j;
    for (i = 1; i < MAP_SIZE; ++i){
        j = i - 1;
        if (map[j].indexFrom == map[i].indexFrom)
            return 0;
        if (map[j].indexTo == map[i].indexTo)
            return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}

int is_valid(Map map) {
    qsort(map, MAP_SIZE, sizeof(MapEntry), map_comparator);
    if (!is_map_valid(map)) return 0;
    return 1;
}


int permute(void *data, int nblobs, int szblob, const Map map){
    int i, tmpFrom, tmpTo;
    void * a = (void *)malloc(szblob);
    char *p = data;

    /* check if map has duplicate keys */
    /* sort the list, then check whether or not the map is valid */
    if (!is_valid(map)) return 0;
    /* where issues occur */

    for (i = 0; i < nblobs; ++i){

        tmpFrom = map[i].indexFrom;

        tmpTo = map[i].indexTo;

        memcpy(a, &p[tmpFrom*szblob], szblob);

        memcpy(&p[tmpFrom*szblob], &p[tmpTo*szblob], szblob);

        memcpy(&p[tmpTo*szblob], a, szblob);

    }

    return 1;

}
/* build mapping */
void build_map(Map map){
    map[0].indexFrom = 0;
    map[0].indexTo = 3;
    map[1].indexFrom = 3;
    map[1].indexTo = 2;
    map[2].indexFrom = 2;
    map[2].indexTo = 1;
    map[3].indexFrom = 1;
    map[3].indexTo = 0;

}
```

Comment: Why would the indexes in the MapEntry be `int *` instead of plain `int`?  Especially on a 64-bit machine, using dynamically allocated pointers instead of simple `int` in the structure wastes a _lot_ of memory (using something like 48 bytes with the dynamic allocation overhead instead of just 16 if the MapEntry is dynamically allocated or 8 if it is not).

Comment: I did not know this. The code should now reflect the fixed struct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are a victim of the non-standard GCC extension that is enabled by default and [allows](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.1.2/gcc/Pointer-Arith.html) [pointer arithmetics](http://www.cs.umd.edu/class/sum2003/cmsc311/Notes/BitOp/pointer.html) on pointers to void and pointers to function by treating the size of a void or of a function as 1. This extension can be disabled by specifying a C standard as, say, C99, using `-std` option — for example, `-std=c99` (see [gcc manual page](http://bama.ua.edu/cgi-bin/man-cgi?gcc) for details). Alternatively, you may ask gcc to issue a warning for such cases by specifying `-Wpointer-arith` option.

Back to the problem, consider what happens when you write `&data[tmpFrom]`. An address pointed by `data` is taken, then `tmpFrom` bytes are added to that address. What you want instead is to add `tmpFrom * sizeof(int)` bytes. To achieve that, you have to either manually calculate required number of bytes based on the value of `tmpFrom` and the size of `int` type, or declare `data` pointer as a pointer to type `int`. The second is a preferred way to go, but if you really want your functions to support arbitrary data types, then you have to fall back to a harder, first approach.

Below is a list of warnings generated by clang (it is generally a lot better with diagnostics):

```
$ clang -Wall -pedantic -o test ./test.c
./test.c:109:18: warning: subscript of a pointer to void is a GNU extension [-pedantic,-Wpointer-arith]
                memcpy(a, &data[tmpFrom], szblob);
                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/secure/_string.h:55:36: note: expanded from macro 'memcpy'
   ? __builtin___memcpy_chk (dest, src, len, __darwin_obsz0 (dest))     \
                                   ^
./test.c:109:13: warning: ISO C forbids taking the address of an expression of type 'void' [-pedantic]
                memcpy(a, &data[tmpFrom], szblob);
                ~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/secure/_string.h:55:36: note: expanded from macro 'memcpy'
   ? __builtin___memcpy_chk (dest, src, len, __darwin_obsz0 (dest))     \
                                   ^
./test.c:109:18: warning: subscript of a pointer to void is a GNU extension [-pedantic,-Wpointer-arith]
                memcpy(a, &data[tmpFrom], szblob);
                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/secure/_string.h:56:33: note: expanded from macro 'memcpy'
   : __inline_memcpy_chk (dest, src, len))
                                ^
./test.c:109:13: warning: ISO C forbids taking the address of an expression of type 'void' [-pedantic]
                memcpy(a, &data[tmpFrom], szblob);
                ~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/secure/_string.h:56:33: note: expanded from macro 'memcpy'
   : __inline_memcpy_chk (dest, src, len))
                                ^
./test.c:111:15: warning: subscript of a pointer to void is a GNU extension [-pedantic,-Wpointer-arith]
                memcpy(&data[tmpFrom], &data[tmpTo], szblob);
                ~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/secure/_string.h:54:21: note: expanded from macro 'memcpy'
  ((__darwin_obsz0 (dest) != (size_t) -1)                               \
                    ^
/usr/include/secure/_common.h:38:55: note: expanded from macro '__darwin_obsz0'
#define __darwin_obsz0(object) __builtin_object_size (object, 0)
                                                      ^~~~~~
./test.c:111:10: warning: ISO C forbids taking the address of an expression of type 'void' [-pedantic]
                memcpy(&data[tmpFrom], &data[tmpTo], szblob);
                ~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/secure/_string.h:54:21: note: expanded from macro 'memcpy'
  ((__darwin_obsz0 (dest) != (size_t) -1)                               \
                    ^
/usr/include/secure/_common.h:38:55: note: expanded from macro '__darwin_obsz0'
#define __darwin_obsz0(object) __builtin_object_size (object, 0)
                                                      ^~~~~~
./test.c:111:15: warning: subscript of a pointer to void is a GNU extension [-pedantic,-Wpointer-arith]
                memcpy(&data[tmpFrom], &data[tmpTo], szblob);
                ~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/secure/_string.h:55:30: note: expanded from macro 'memcpy'
   ? __builtin___memcpy_chk (dest, src, len, __darwin_obsz0 (dest))     \
                             ^
./test.c:111:10: warning: ISO C forbids taking the address of an expression of type 'void' [-pedantic]
                memcpy(&data[tmpFrom], &data[tmpTo], szblob);
                ~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/secure/_string.h:55:30: note: expanded from macro 'memcpy'
   ? __builtin___memcpy_chk (dest, src, len, __darwin_obsz0 (dest))     \
                             ^
./test.c:111:31: warning: subscript of a pointer to void is a GNU extension [-pedantic,-Wpointer-arith]
                memcpy(&data[tmpFrom], &data[tmpTo], szblob);
                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/secure/_string.h:55:36: note: expanded from macro 'memcpy'
   ? __builtin___memcpy_chk (dest, src, len, __darwin_obsz0 (dest))     \
                                   ^
./test.c:111:26: warning: ISO C forbids taking the address of an expression of type 'void' [-pedantic]
                memcpy(&data[tmpFrom], &data[tmpTo], szblob);
                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/secure/_string.h:55:36: note: expanded from macro 'memcpy'
   ? __builtin___memcpy_chk (dest, src, len, __darwin_obsz0 (dest))     \
                                   ^
./test.c:111:15: warning: subscript of a pointer to void is a GNU extension [-pedantic,-Wpointer-arith]
                memcpy(&data[tmpFrom], &data[tmpTo], szblob);
                ~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/secure/_string.h:55:62: note: expanded from macro 'memcpy'
   ? __builtin___memcpy_chk (dest, src, len, __darwin_obsz0 (dest))     \
                                                             ^
/usr/include/secure/_common.h:38:55: note: expanded from macro '__darwin_obsz0'
#define __darwin_obsz0(object) __builtin_object_size (object, 0)
                                                      ^~~~~~
./test.c:111:10: warning: ISO C forbids taking the address of an expression of type 'void' [-pedantic]
                memcpy(&data[tmpFrom], &data[tmpTo], szblob);
                ~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/secure/_string.h:55:62: note: expanded from macro 'memcpy'
   ? __builtin___memcpy_chk (dest, src, len, __darwin_obsz0 (dest))     \
                                                             ^
/usr/include/secure/_common.h:38:55: note: expanded from macro '__darwin_obsz0'
#define __darwin_obsz0(object) __builtin_object_size (object, 0)
                                                      ^~~~~~
./test.c:111:15: warning: subscript of a pointer to void is a GNU extension [-pedantic,-Wpointer-arith]
                memcpy(&data[tmpFrom], &data[tmpTo], szblob);
                ~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/secure/_string.h:56:27: note: expanded from macro 'memcpy'
   : __inline_memcpy_chk (dest, src, len))
                          ^
./test.c:111:10: warning: ISO C forbids taking the address of an expression of type 'void' [-pedantic]
                memcpy(&data[tmpFrom], &data[tmpTo], szblob);
                ~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/secure/_string.h:56:27: note: expanded from macro 'memcpy'
   : __inline_memcpy_chk (dest, src, len))
                          ^
./test.c:111:31: warning: subscript of a pointer to void is a GNU extension [-pedantic,-Wpointer-arith]
                memcpy(&data[tmpFrom], &data[tmpTo], szblob);
                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/secure/_string.h:56:33: note: expanded from macro 'memcpy'
   : __inline_memcpy_chk (dest, src, len))
                                ^
./test.c:111:26: warning: ISO C forbids taking the address of an expression of type 'void' [-pedantic]
                memcpy(&data[tmpFrom], &data[tmpTo], szblob);
                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/secure/_string.h:56:33: note: expanded from macro 'memcpy'
   : __inline_memcpy_chk (dest, src, len))
                                ^
./test.c:113:15: warning: subscript of a pointer to void is a GNU extension [-pedantic,-Wpointer-arith]
                memcpy(&data[tmpTo], a, szblob);
                ~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/secure/_string.h:54:21: note: expanded from macro 'memcpy'
  ((__darwin_obsz0 (dest) != (size_t) -1)                               \
                    ^
/usr/include/secure/_common.h:38:55: note: expanded from macro '__darwin_obsz0'
#define __darwin_obsz0(object) __builtin_object_size (object, 0)
                                                      ^~~~~~
./test.c:113:10: warning: ISO C forbids taking the address of an expression of type 'void' [-pedantic]
                memcpy(&data[tmpTo], a, szblob);
                ~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/secure/_string.h:54:21: note: expanded from macro 'memcpy'
  ((__darwin_obsz0 (dest) != (size_t) -1)                               \
                    ^
/usr/include/secure/_common.h:38:55: note: expanded from macro '__darwin_obsz0'
#define __darwin_obsz0(object) __builtin_object_size (object, 0)
                                                      ^~~~~~
./test.c:113:15: warning: subscript of a pointer to void is a GNU extension [-pedantic,-Wpointer-arith]
                memcpy(&data[tmpTo], a, szblob);
                ~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/secure/_string.h:55:30: note: expanded from macro 'memcpy'
   ? __builtin___memcpy_chk (dest, src, len, __darwin_obsz0 (dest))     \
                             ^
./test.c:113:10: warning: ISO C forbids taking the address of an expression of type 'void' [-pedantic]
                memcpy(&data[tmpTo], a, szblob);
                ~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/secure/_string.h:55:30: note: expanded from macro 'memcpy'
   ? __builtin___memcpy_chk (dest, src, len, __darwin_obsz0 (dest))     \
                             ^
./test.c:113:15: warning: subscript of a pointer to void is a GNU extension [-pedantic,-Wpointer-arith]
                memcpy(&data[tmpTo], a, szblob);
                ~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/secure/_string.h:55:62: note: expanded from macro 'memcpy'
   ? __builtin___memcpy_chk (dest, src, len, __darwin_obsz0 (dest))     \
                                                             ^
/usr/include/secure/_common.h:38:55: note: expanded from macro '__darwin_obsz0'
#define __darwin_obsz0(object) __builtin_object_size (object, 0)
                                                      ^~~~~~
./test.c:113:10: warning: ISO C forbids taking the address of an expression of type 'void' [-pedantic]
                memcpy(&data[tmpTo], a, szblob);
                ~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/secure/_string.h:55:62: note: expanded from macro 'memcpy'
   ? __builtin___memcpy_chk (dest, src, len, __darwin_obsz0 (dest))     \
                                                             ^
/usr/include/secure/_common.h:38:55: note: expanded from macro '__darwin_obsz0'
#define __darwin_obsz0(object) __builtin_object_size (object, 0)
                                                      ^~~~~~
./test.c:113:15: warning: subscript of a pointer to void is a GNU extension [-pedantic,-Wpointer-arith]
                memcpy(&data[tmpTo], a, szblob);
                ~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/secure/_string.h:56:27: note: expanded from macro 'memcpy'
   : __inline_memcpy_chk (dest, src, len))
                          ^
./test.c:113:10: warning: ISO C forbids taking the address of an expression of type 'void' [-pedantic]
                memcpy(&data[tmpTo], a, szblob);
                ~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/secure/_string.h:56:27: note: expanded from macro 'memcpy'
   : __inline_memcpy_chk (dest, src, len))
                          ^
24 warnings generated.
```

Once the above warnings are fixed, it should have worked. However, there are two more problems...

The first problem is incorrect expected result. It should be `3, -1, 1, 2` and not `3, -1, 2, 1`. The mapping should be sorted like this:

```
0,3
1,0
2,1
3,2
```

And the permutation should be done in four steps:

```
1) 2, 3, -1, 1
2) 3, 2, -1, 1
3) 3, -1, 2, 1
4) 3, -1, 1, 2
```

The second problem is incorrect sorting. By performing two sorts, first on "from" values and second on "to" values, you end up with a mapping sorted only by "to" (the last sort you invoke). What should be done instead is a single sort using a predicate that compares both "from" and "to" of each element. For example:

```
int map_comparator(const void *a, const void *b)
{
    const MapEntry *s1 = a;
    const MapEntry *s2 = b;
    if (*s2->indexFrom != *s1->indexFrom) {
        return *s1->indexFrom - *s2->indexFrom;
    } else {
        return *s1->indexTo - *s2->indexTo;
    }
}
```

Once the above is fixed, everything will work. Other than that, there are only few more suggestions to your code that might be helpful:

1. You are using way too many dynamic allocations. Consider re-thinking how you do it. For example, I don't see a need to have `indexFrom` and `indexTo` fields of `MapEntry` structure dynamically allocated.
2. You have unnecessary casts to `void *`. For example: `void * a = (void *)malloc(szblob);` should be just `void *a = malloc(szblob);`.
3. Unnecessary casts from `void *` to other pointer types like `int *`. This is not necessary in C where `void *` pointer is implicitly convertible to pointers of other types. This is not true for C++, however.
4. Do not `typedef` structures unless the goal is to create an opaque type (which is not in your case). Typing `struct` may seem like a lot of typing, but it serves as a great hints about the type to those C developers who read your code. For example, see Chapter 5 of the [Linux Kernel Coding Style](http://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/CodingStyle) for a great explanation.

I encourage you to fix your code yourself, but here is your code with minimal necessary changes to make it work, for your reference:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#define MAP_SIZE 4

typedef struct MapEntry {
    int * indexFrom;
    int * indexTo;
} MapEntry;

typedef MapEntry * Map;

int permute(void *data, int nblobs, int szblob, const Map map);

void build_map(Map);
void build_data(int *);
int is_map_valid(Map);
void print_map(Map);
int is_valid(Map);

int map_comparator(const void * a, const void * b);

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    int nblobs, * data, i;
    size_t szblob;
    Map map = (Map)malloc(sizeof(Map));
    data = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int) * 4);

    build_map(map);

    data[0] = 1;
    data[1] = 3;
    data[2] = -1;
    data[3] = 2;

    nblobs = 4;
    szblob = sizeof(int);

    if (!permute(data, nblobs, szblob, map)) {
        printf("Invalid Map\n");
        return 0;
    }

    i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < szblob; ++i) {
        printf("%d ", data[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}

void print_map(Map map){
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < MAP_SIZE; ++i) {
        printf("[%d - %d]\n", *map[i].indexFrom, *map[i].indexTo);
    }
}

int map_comparator(const void *a, const void *b)
{
    const MapEntry *s1 = a;
    const MapEntry *s2 = b;
    if (*s2->indexFrom != *s1->indexFrom) {
        return *s1->indexFrom - *s2->indexFrom;
    } else {
        return *s1->indexTo - *s2->indexTo;
    }
}

int is_map_valid(Map map) {
    int i,j;
    for (i = 1; i < MAP_SIZE; ++i){
        j = i - 1;
        if (*map[j].indexFrom == *map[i].indexFrom)
            return 0;
        if (*map[j].indexTo == *map[i].indexTo)
            return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}

int is_valid(Map map) {
    qsort(map, MAP_SIZE, sizeof(MapEntry), map_comparator);
    if (!is_map_valid(map)) return 0;
    return 1;
}


int permute(void *data, int nblobs, int szblob, const Map map){
    int i, tmpFrom, tmpTo;
    void * a = (void *)malloc(szblob);
    char *p = data;

    /* check if map has duplicate keys */
    /* sort the list, then check whether or not the map is valid */
    if (!is_valid(map)) return 0;
    /* where issues occur */

    for (i = 0; i < nblobs; ++i){

        tmpFrom = *map[i].indexFrom;

        tmpTo = *map[i].indexTo;

        memcpy(a, &p[tmpFrom*szblob], szblob);

        memcpy(&p[tmpFrom*szblob], &p[tmpTo*szblob], szblob);

        memcpy(&p[tmpTo*szblob], a, szblob);

    }

    return 1;

}
/* build mapping */
void build_map(Map map){
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < MAP_SIZE; ++i) {
        map[i].indexFrom = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int));
        map[i].indexTo = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int));
    }

    *map[0].indexFrom = 0;
    *map[0].indexTo = 3;

    *map[1].indexFrom = 3;
    *map[1].indexTo = 2;

    *map[2].indexFrom = 2;
    *map[2].indexTo = 1;

    *map[3].indexFrom = 1;
    *map[3].indexTo = 0;

}
```

Hope it helps. Stay warm and Good Luck!

Comment: First of all. Absurdly helpful post, thank you. Secondly, 1) Fixed 2) I will remove these 3) This was to make the data type abstract. So mapping re-order operations could be performed on any type, not just necessarily ints 4) Very interesting, I assumed typedef'ing a struct helped readability, but the whole naming on the top and the bottom confuses me. Thanks for your comparator code as well.

Answer (score 1):

Over and above the issues outlined so ably by [Vlad Lazarenko](https://stackoverflow.com/users/405725/vlad-lazarenko), I think you have some memory allocation problems.  (I'm not talking about the excessive allocation required by the pointers in the structure, either.)

In `main()`, you have:

```
Map map = (Map)malloc(sizeof(Map));
```

This allocates the size of one `MapEntry *` for `map`, whereas you probably had in mind to allocate at least the space for a `MapEntry` and probably for 4 `MapEntry` values.  You then call:

```
build_map(map);
```

and inside the function, you treat it as if you had an array of 4 `MapEntry` values.  You should, therefore, write:

```
Map map = (Map)malloc(MAP_SIZE * sizeof(*map));
```

If you ran the code under [`valgrind`](http://valgrind.org/), it would surely have let you know about this problem too.  There are those who excoriate programmers who use casts with `malloc()` in C; I'm not one of those (I frequently use the cast myself).  But be aware of the reasons for the criticism.

You could simplify the code by using:

```
int data[MAP_SIZE] = { 1, 3, -1, 2 };
```

Maybe this is just an exercise in using `malloc()` as often as possible.

You could even go radical and avoid all dynamic memory allocation:

```
typedef struct MapEntry
{
    int indexFrom;
    int indexTo;
} MapEntry;

int main(void)  // argc, argv unused
{
    int nblobs, i; 
    size_t szblob;
    MapEntry map[] = { { 0, 3 }, { 3, 2 }, { 3, 1 }, { 1, 0 } };
    enum { NUM_MAPENTRIES = sizeof(map) / sizeof(map[0]) };
    int data[]     = { 1, 3, -1, 2 };
    enum { NUM_DATAENTRIES = sizeof(data) / sizeof(data[0]) };
```

I think your `permute()` function needs one more argument — the number of map entries passed.

---

One further problem; your `is_valid ()` function permutes (sorts) your `map` array, so the order of operations specified in `main()` is not the order of operations performed in `permute()`.  Also, the `is_valid_map()` check is, I think, supposed to check whether any two mappings have the same from and to indexes; you could do that without sorting, albeit with O(N<sup>2</sup>) complexity instead of O(N log N) complexity.  But you'd not permute the map when doing it.

I ended up with:

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct MapEntry
{
    int indexFrom;
    int indexTo;
} MapEntry;

static int  permute(void *data, size_t nblobs, size_t szblob, MapEntry *map, size_t szmap);
static void print_data(const char *tag, int *data, size_t ndata);
static void print_map(const char *tag, MapEntry *map, size_t szmap);

int main(void)
{
    MapEntry map[] = { { 0, 3 }, { 3, 2 }, { 3, 1 }, { 1, 0 } };
    enum { NUM_MAPENTRIES = sizeof(map) / sizeof(map[0]) };
    int data[]     = { 1, 3, -1, 2 };
    enum { NUM_DATAENTRIES = sizeof(data) / sizeof(data[0]) };

    print_data("Initial data", data, NUM_DATAENTRIES);
    print_map(" Initial map", map, NUM_MAPENTRIES);

    if (!permute(data, NUM_DATAENTRIES, sizeof(int), map, NUM_MAPENTRIES))
    {
        printf("Invalid Map\n");
        return 0;
    }

    print_data("Result", data, NUM_DATAENTRIES);

    return 0;
}

static void print_data(const char *tag, int *data, size_t ndata)
{
    const char *pad = ": ";
    fputs(tag, stdout);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < ndata; ++i)
    {
        printf("%s%2d", pad, data[i]);
        pad = ", ";
    }
    putchar('\n');
}

static void print_map(const char *tag, MapEntry * map, size_t szmap)
{
    printf("%s:", tag);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < szmap; ++i)
        printf(" [%d - %d]", map[i].indexFrom, map[i].indexTo);
    putchar('\n');
}

static int is_map_valid(MapEntry *map, size_t szmap)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < szmap; ++i)
    {
        for (size_t j = i + 1; j < szmap; ++j)
        {
            if ((map[j].indexFrom == map[i].indexFrom) &&
                (map[j].indexTo == map[i].indexTo))
            {
                printf("map[%zu].indexFrom = %d = map[%zu].indexFrom = %d\n",
                        j, map[j].indexFrom, i, map[i].indexFrom);
                printf("map[%zu].indexTo = %d = map[%zu].indexTo = %d\n",
                        j, map[j].indexTo, i, map[i].indexTo);
                return 0;
            }
        }
    }
    return 1;
}

static int permute(void *data, size_t nblobs, size_t szblob, MapEntry *map, size_t szmap)
{
    char  tmp[szblob];
    char *base = data;

    if (!is_map_valid(map, szmap))
        return 0;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < szmap; ++i)
    {
        print_map("Switch", &map[i], 1);
        print_data("Before", data, nblobs);
        size_t tmpFr = map[i].indexFrom;
        size_t tmpTo = map[i].indexTo;
        assert(tmpFr < nblobs && tmpTo < nblobs);
        char *src = base + (tmpFr * szblob);
        char *tgt = base + (tmpTo * szblob);
        memcpy(tmp, src, szblob);
        memcpy(src, tgt, szblob);
        memcpy(tgt, tmp, szblob);
        print_data(" After", data, nblobs);
    }

    return 1;
}
```

Sample output:

```
Initial data:  1,  3, -1,  2
 Initial map: [0 - 3] [3 - 2] [3 - 1] [1 - 0]
Switch: [0 - 3]
Before:  1,  3, -1,  2
 After:  2,  3, -1,  1
Switch: [3 - 2]
Before:  2,  3, -1,  1
 After:  2,  3,  1, -1
Switch: [3 - 1]
Before:  2,  3,  1, -1
 After:  2, -1,  1,  3
Switch: [1 - 0]
Before:  2, -1,  1,  3
 After: -1,  2,  1,  3
Result: -1,  2,  1,  3
```

This is different from the result you expect, but I'm not sure how you get what you expect from the starting data.